# include common html in various places of a template using django

Tags: html, django, templates

I have several html templates that extend a base template using django. In these templates there are common html/django snippets that I would like to have in one place and then rendered in the various places they appear in the templates.

i have looked at `include` tags, but I'm not sure this is what I need.

Any suggestions or explanations appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If your are trying to have a same piece if HTML included then, include tag is the best way to do it. 
That is the way recommended in Documentation as well, if there is a better way of doing this i would be interested too


     {% include "subtemplate.html" %}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include is the way... you can keep your snippets in a template subdirectory (like `templates/includes/....`) for example and do `{% include "includes/mytemplate.html %}`.